# Remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => 20
    )
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => 10
    )
    (
        [0] => G
        [1] => 5
    )
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => 15
    )
)
```

I would like to remove duplicate values and sum just a row of array: What I want :

```
   Array
    (
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 35 // <= sum : 20 + 15
        )    
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => 10
        )    
        (
            [0] => G
            [1] => 5
        )
    )
```

My code :

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

    $arr = array(
        'GoodMainCode'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['GoodMainCode']), // <= like A in the example
        'title'=> persian_sql_to_php($row['GoodName']),
        'author'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['moalef']),
        'publisher'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Nasher']),
        'translator'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Motarjem']),
        'price'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['SellPrice1']),
        'isbn'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['ISBN']),
        'amount'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['Amount']), // <= if GoodMainCode is same key, I must sum it.
        'year_of_publish'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['SaleChap']),
        'period_print'=>persian_sql_to_php($row['NobateChap'])
    );

    array_push($mjson,$arr);
}

//to remove duplicate values and sum amount key values

foreach($mjson as $v){

    if(!isset($result[$v['GoodMainCode']]))
        $result[$v['GoodMainCode']] = $v;
    else
        $result[$v['GoodMainCode']]['amount'] += $v['amount'];
}
```

But my `foreach` creates an extra value! 
It creates a `GoodMainCode` value.

My output:

(To read output copy/paste into http://json.parser.online.fr/):

```
{"7916":{"id":"1168","GoodMainCode":"7916","title":"\u0632\u064a\u0631\u062f\u0633\u062a\u064a \u0637\u0644\u0642\u064a CLIP BOARD","author":" ","publisher":"\u0641\u0642\u064a\u0647\u064a \u0645\u0647\u0631","translator":" ","price":"20625","isbn":" ","amount":"0","year_of_publish":"0","period_print":"0"},"7989":{"id":"16827","GoodMainCode":"7989","title":"\u064a\u062f\u0643 \u0627\u062a\u0648\u062f5\u0645\u064a\u0644 \u0643\u0648\u0647 \u0646\u0648\u0631B6","author":" ","publisher":"","translator":" ","price":"108025","isbn":" ","amount":61,"year_of_publish":"0","period_print":"0"},"8350":{"id":"1225","GoodMainCode":"8350","title":"\u064a\u062f\u0643 \u0627\u062a\u0648\u062f\u0637\u0631\u0627\u062d\u064a2\u0645\u064a\u0644JBN","author":" ","publisher":"","translator":" ","price":"3375","isbn":" ","amount":"0","year_of_publish":"0","period_print":"0"}}
```

In my output, `7916`,`7989`,`8350` are extra.

Comment: It doesn't *create* that key/value pair, it's already part of your input array.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a quicker way, however here's one way to achieve it (kind of).

```
$array = array(
    array('A', 20),
    array('B', 10),
    array('C', 5),
    array('A', 15),
);

$sum_array();
foreach ($array as $internal_array)
{
    // using the letter here as a key, so we can increment that value using += operator
    $sum_array[$internal_array[0]] += $internal_array[1];
}

// gives you (not exactly what you want but more manageable in my opinion)
/*
[
    'A' => 35,
    'B' => 10,
    'C' => 15,
]
*/
```

Of course this requires that your multidimensional array is consistent and always has the key and value pairs.